# Phonegap Build Inappbrowser Zooming

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

I want to open a website through the Inappbrowser and allow zooming. The browser opens the page, but zooming doesn't work. I compile the app with build.phonegap.com. I use the version 6.3.0 of Cordova.

index.html:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes', 'zoom=yes');
```

config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'yes' value for the zoom,

try using percentage or number.

For your record, 1 = 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
        window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes,zoom=yes');
```

`Options` is a comma separated string.